# Write, with ffmpeg, every 30 seconds wav file from ip stream to file.temp and change the name to timestamp.wav after

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to record IP stream and write every 30 seconds to wav file.

Here is my  bash script code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function start_ffmpeg_stream ()
{
    address=$1 #This is IP stream address
    ffmpeg_option=$2 # "?overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=250000"
    folder_name=$3 #folderName
    channel_number=$4 #i
    #local pid      
    ffmpeg  -loglevel 8 -thread_queue_size 1500 -i "$address$ffmpeg_option" -c copy\
        -vn -f segment -segment_time 30 -ar 8000 -acodec pcm_s32le -ac 1 -strftime 1 /"$folder_name"/"X$channel_number""_""%s.wav"&     
    pid=$!
    echo "$Start ffmpeg, pid is - $pid" 
    __="$pid"
}
ffmpegOptions="?overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=250000"
folderName="/wav_files"
start_ffmpeg_stream "udp://224.10.0.1"  "$ffmpegOptions" "$folderName" "1"
```

Now the wav file name is like "X000001_unix_time_stamp.wav".

I want to write the file name in writeing time something like "X000001_unix_time_stamp.temp"

And when the 30 seconds done and the  FFmpeg finish to write this 30 seconds, I want that FFmpeg changes the name to "X000001_unix_time_stamp.wav"

And keep writing next 30 seconds.

The only change that i want is,  when FFmpeg writing it write in temp name and after FFmpeg finish to write it change the name.

It's seem to case when i donloaded a file so until the donload not finish the file has a temp name and when it done the name change to const name.

Comment: Not implemented.

Comment: Do you know about another ways to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) is what you are looking for, specifically the `-segment_list` flag which writes a file containing all the segment paths which have been written to and closed. You can also limit this file size using the `-segment_list_size` flag so you don't end up with a huge log file. Parse this file to do what you want with the completed files

Comment: You are my hero!